# Open Graph: How do I create custom objects and associate custom actions with them?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, object, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to create a custom object (`objnew`) and am trying to associate an action with it (`actnew`). All is good till now.

Now, I have to write code, where I have to create objects of type `objnew` and the associated action.

How do I create the objects? I got the sample code to publish it to Facebook:

```
curl -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
 -F 'newobj=http://samples.ogp.me/467564296596508' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/myapp:newact'
```

Now this `newobj` is a reference. How do I create this and get the URL?

Comment: e.g http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects. Assume that custom object is recipe. Now,  I want to add multiple recipes that users can refer to while publishing stories. How can I do that using APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Note edit below please!***

> Now, I want to add multiple recipes that users can refer to while publishing stories. How can I do that using APIs?

You *don’t* do that using the API.

**Open Graph objects are basically just URLs refering to pages that have the appropriate OG meta tags set.**

So just set up these URLs on your site – you can do that manually, if you like, or make it something database-driven, where there’s just a parameter in the URL that let’s your script pull the appropriate data from some table and have it populate the OG meta tags with that data.

Then, when publishing an action, you just give the URL of one of *those* objects as the parameter – Facebook does the rest, it “scrapes” the URL and pulls the data from there.

The way you’re doing it now, using `http://samples.ogp.me/467564296596508` – well, that’s as the URL says basically just for *samples*. When publishing “real” actions, the objects should be *real* objects as well – that is, objects on your site with URLs pointing to your site.

And use the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check your objects (and fix any problems it might find) – that helps preventing problems you might run into as a beginner on the subject.

---

**Edit:** Things have changed since I originally wrote this – Facebook now allows you to create objects via API, and those object can belong to either your app, or a specific user.

For full documentation see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api

Comment: Thank you CBroe. This was simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your story's content hosted on your website and have the Facebook scraper create the object then, doing what CBroe's suggests works great.

I just wanted to add that It is possible to have Facebook host your objects by invoking the graph api to create them. Note that this will create an activity log entry for the Facebook user invoked the api.

**Here is an example of how to create an object using the api (in javascrip)**:

```js
FB.api(
  'me/objects/yourappdomain:objectypename',
  'post',
  {
    og:title: title,
    og:type: yourappdomain:objectypename,
    yourappdomain:customobjectpropertyname: propertyvalue,
  },
  function(response) {
    // save the created object's id returned as you will need to specify it when creating your storie's action
  }
);
```

To get example code that shows how to do this for your custom object type go to your app's Facebook developer page. Click on Open Graph -> Object Types -> Get Code (next to the object type you want to create).

[See Using Objects on Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects)